# Do vaccinated people not have zero risk of mortality by Covid 19?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination, epidemiology, covid, immunology

[This video by Vox](https://youtu.be/K3odScka55A) says people who are vaccinated have zero risk of mortality by Covid 19.

But [NDTV reports](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-9V_MCCC6E&t=21s) (at 00:21 and again at 07:53 in the video) that even fully vaccinated 8 frontline medical workers have died due to Covid-19, through breakthrough infections.

> Indian Medical Association: India has lost 269 doctors in second wave.
> 3% of doctors who died were fully vaccinated.

**Are there other reports of post vaccination mortality due to Covid 19?**

So given that the news is from a reputable source and if there other such reports, **is the Vox claim that vaccine offers zero mortality risk is wrong??** and is only applicable to trials and not large number of people in real world?

---

Edit: For many people who are having trouble understanding this

1. The news outlet is not giving out any science, its simply givong out stats which were given out by Indian Medical Association.
2. 66% of medical personell have been vaccinated in India
3. 269 medical personell have been dead in the second wave, out of which 3% were vaccinated. Which is 8 people.

As of Google there are around 1.16 million doctors. 66% of them are vaccinated, so 0.76 million are vaccinated. Now 269 of doctors are dead in second wave, **out of those 269 people, 3% were vaccinated**. So 8 people died of covid despite being vaccinated.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124464/discussion-on-question-by-mr-green-gold-do-vaccinated-people-not-have-zero-risk).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it's not zero, even in the US. The March 20 Vox report is talking about the clinical trials, which were conducted on tens of thousands of people, who were generally healthy.

In the subsequent rollout in the US, some vaccinated people have died as CNN [reported](https://edition.cnn.com/2021/04/14/health/breakthrough-infections-covid-vaccines-cdc/index.html) in mid-April:

> About 5,800 people who have been vaccinated against coronavirus have become infected anyway, the US Centers for Disease Control and Prevention tells CNN.
>
> Some became seriously ill and 74 people died, the CDC said. It said 396 -- 7% -- of those who got infected after they were vaccinated required hospitalization.
>
> This is the CDC's first public accounting of breakthrough cases, and the agency is searching for patterns based on patient age and gender, location, type of vaccine, variants and other factors. [...]
>
> About 77 million people in the US are fully vaccinated against coronavirus, according to a CNN analysis of CDC data.

So that's almost 1 in a million deaths among the vaccinated, in the US. Clearly not something that would have been likely caught in the clinical trials.

By April 26, [CDC's website](https://www.cdc.gov/vaccines/covid-19/health-departments/past-breakthrough-data.html) reported 132 deaths in the US among the vaccinated, which had reached 95 million by then. However, this report also says that "20 (15%) of the 132 fatal cases were reported as asymptomatic or not related to COVID-19." These [20 or so] might have been excluded from CNN's earlier report.

There most recent data, as I'm writing this, [seems](https://www.cdc.gov/vaccines/covid-19/health-departments/breakthrough-cases.html) to be from May 10: 223 deaths among the vaccinated (42 of which " asymptomatic or not related to COVID-19") out of 115 million fully vaccinated.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124463/discussion-on-answer-by-fizz-do-vaccinated-people-not-have-zero-risk-of-mortalit).